# How to convert a numpy ndarray to image in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, data-conversion

I have an array of specific numbers with 784 elements:
[67, 67, 40, 61, 79, 41, 79, 67, 40, 67, 67, 40, 61, 79, 41, 91, 79, 45, 93, 41, 67, 91, 78,...]
range is from 0 to 255

My code is:

```
ImageArray = [67, 67, 40, 61, 79, 41, 79, 67, 40, 67, 67, 40, 61,...]
ImageArray = np.array(ImageArray)
ImageArray = np.reshape(ImageArray, (28,28))
data = im.fromarray(ImageArray)
data.save('image.png')
```

but image its just black
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8HlZ.png)

How can I get an image in 1 channel from 0 to 255?

Comment: `data = im.fromarray(ImageArray, mode='L')`